# Is branch level read/write access permission available in Bonobo Git Server?

Tags: git, bonobo

I wanted to give write permission to the master branch only to a group of people. It seems there are no such option in Bonobo Git Server hosted in IIS server.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bonobo` doesn't have this feature you can use `Gogs` , `Gitlab` ,or `Gitea`  these git's servers have a lots of feature doesn't exist in `bonobo`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right - there is no such functionality in Bonobo Git Server implemented yet.

I've found a partial solution for your problem. You can hide and show branch, but only for all user and without write/read permissions. Just git clients can see branch or not. Check this if it will help you in some way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069629/git-over-http-transfer-protocols-branch-permissions

Comment: I've edited my answer. It's not 100% solution, but I think it's some step forward.

Comment: yep, my questions was deleted, indeed. I've put my question on fiddler, you can lookup if you're interested https://dotnetfiddle.net/rDeYgl